# How do I create dynamic models in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

So I have a questionnaire app and want to store all the answers in some model, to further send it to the backend. The questions are passed to the component. The problem that I am facing is storing the answers.

So here is my component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(question, questionIndex) in questions">
            <label>{{question.question}}</label>
            <select v-model="answers[questionIndex]" class="form-control">
                <option v-for="answer in question.answers" v-bind:value="answer.value">{{answer.value}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['questions'],
        data() {
            return {
                answers: []
            }
        },
        methods: {

        },
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

The thing is - when I select and answer - the `answers` data property is still an empty array and does not append a new `key => value` to it. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Chceck this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/pxo24

Comment: @dhruwlalan, so I have exactly the same for displaying the questions, and no problems with that - as they are showing correctly. Now I don't know how to store the answers, as the answersList array simply not getting populated.

Comment: what version of vue are you using?

Comment: @dhruwlalan vue2

Comment: The above codesandbox works on vue version 2..!

Comment: @dhruwlalan I have checked - that is exactly what I need. Somehow it does not work on my end, I think I need to check what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @dhruwlalan - found the reason for the difference. The problem is that I am trying to use string based keys for question answers, as I need to record the question key for the answer.